# Form Entry, Review then Update

Tags: forms, coldfusion

I'm creating a form where the user will enter data, then click "Review" to see the data they entered. Then after review, "Save" the record.

I'm using a `<cfform>` to submit the form but wonder how to submit the data to the database from the "Review" page since there's no form here.

Should I set variables like `FORM.Name = VARIABLES.Name` to display on the review page, then convert them back after they submit the "Save"?

Not really sure what to do here. Overthinking?

Comment: i'd say you're over thinking it. Pass the form to the review page and then pass those form variables as hidden variables to the save page.

Comment: If you'd like to keep from re-inventing the wheel, there's a custom tag from over 10 years ago that automates that for you: [CF_EmbedFields](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1000001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep in form scope. Basic output of form values, using baked in form.fieldList:

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldList#" item="fieldName">

    <cfoutput>
        #fieldName#: #form[fieldName]#<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="#fieldName#" value="#form[fieldName]#">
    </cfoutput>

</cfloop>
```

Link to original form or submit to page where you save it, using values from hidden fields (which should mirror original form values)

A few other ways you could do this, but this seems simplest to me.

Comment: I'm in and out of projects every day, I haven't been able to post back to this question. I may have been over-thinking as stated above. I'll be trying the fieldList solution above, something I didn't know existed. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a second form with hidden input fields for the review page? Confirm would be a  submit button to the page that saves the data to the server.
Second possibility (not that proper): save the data directly into the database and load it for the review from there. Trick: use a flag with "confirmed" and set it if confirmed. Bad part about that: you have to clean up older data that has not been confirmed.

Comment: There are valid use cases for the second option. But agreed it is probably unnecessary in this scenario. A second form with hidden fields should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Billy Cravens answer. This protects against the fields having Embedded Attacks

```
<cfoutput>
    #lcase(fieldName)#: #xmlFormat(form[fieldName])#<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="#fieldName#" value="#xmlFormat(form[fieldName])#" />
</cfoutput>
```

Also this will not work for image uploads. The lcase(fieldName) is to keeps the fields from being displayed as all caps. Lowercase is often easier to read.